# Accessing class created in Module

Tags: ruby, class, object, module

I'm creating a class and everything in it, dynamically, in a module.

(i'm leaving out everything but the creation of the class..)

in 'test.rb'

```
module Model

    def generate(input)
        eval("
            class #{titleString};
                def initialize(#{attrStr});
                    #{instVar}
                end;

                #{attrMethString}; 

            end
        ")
    end
    extend self
end
```

Then i load the module in another ruby-file, 'create.rb'

```
require 'test.rb'

Person = Model.generate('sample.txt')
```

Where 'sample.txt' holds the information for creating the class.

I can "reach" and create instances from the class within 'test.rb', such as:

```
p = Person.new('Joe', 22, 178,'New kid')
```

And when the class is instantiated, i can pass the object to 'create.rb'

But what i want to do, is "reach" the class from 'create.rb', and create the objects there..

Is it possible to assign the un-instantiated class to a variable, and then pass it?

Comment: If this is solved, then click the tick next to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solotuion was to return the name of the Class as a constant..**

```
eval("return #{titleString}")
```